# Отличие scanf/printf от cin/cout в С++

Tags: c++

В чём основное отличие этих способов ввода/вывода? Можно ли в C++ использовать спокойно функции scanf/printf или есть какие-то подводные камни?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf` и `printf` это наследие C, они входят в стандартную библиотеку C, которая полностью поддерживается С++ (хотя сейчас эти языки расходятся). Потоки (`cin` и `cout`) это стандартная (и более новая) библиотека C++. Можно использовать любую библиотеку, или даже обе сразу. *Однако как замечено в комментариях, для доступа к одному и тому же стандартному потоку (`stdin/stdout`) лучше использовать что-то одно, иначе могут быть проблемы с [синхронизацией](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).*

Хотя функции ввода/вывода C более старые, они помощнее, да и поудобнее. Так что в маленьких (особенно учебных) программах чаще используются потоки, а в больших коммерческих чаще можно видеть функции C. Это по личному впечатлению, конечно, вряд ли тут есть достоверная статистика.

Comment: ` и даже смешивать как угодно` - уточните пожалуйста. Я про [sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: @vegorov, нет, я не имел в виду запись в один и тот же файл потоком и `fprintf` одновременно. Как-то в голову не пришло что кто-то так может делать. То же самое насчет `stdio` - может это и будет работать, но делать так явно не стоит.

Comment: я понимаю что Вы имели в виду, но написано ` и даже смешивать как угодно.` лучше оставить ссылку на функцию, где есть пояснения "подводных камней" в комментарии или поправить ответ.

Comment: @vegorov, да, вы правы - если написанное можно понять неправильным образом, обязательно найдется кто-нибудь, кто именно так и поймет. Поправил ответ.